# Tell zend router to put prefix to each url

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, routes

I am working on a website with zend framework 1.12.

However the client is using IIS with no rewriting abilities, so I need to reconfigure zend to create urls like `index.php/controller/action` rather than `/controller/action`.

The easiest & least painful way I see doing it is to somehow tell zend router to put a prefix `index.php` in each url it generates.

The question is, is this possible and how?

Comment: Why do you have no rewriting abilities? Have you tried?: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules

Comment: It is not up to me, it's a client's requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution that works for me.

If anyone else has this problem, here's what I put in my Bootstrap.php:

```
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
$router->removeDefaultRoutes();
$router->addRoute('default', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('index.php', array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index')));
$router->addRoute('compat', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:controller/:action/*', array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index')));
```